# Disable hardware prefetcher on Xeon Phi

Tags: xeon-phi

Is it possible to disable hardware prefetcher on Xeon Phi preferably via programming? I want to measure the percent performance improvement provided by the hardware prefetcher for the STREAM benchmark. I do not want to change the original STREAM benchmark, I want to add some lines of code or a compiler flag that disables the hardware prefetcher.

I am aware of the answer at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-many-integrated-core/topic/520185. I wonder whether there is an update or a geneious workaround.